# How to organize multi-model views in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, partial-views

I'm beginning development on a Rails app and before I start heading in the wrong direction, I'd like to see if there is a common way (ie. best practice) to do this. I have the models `Game` and `Player` in a `has_many :through` relationship. And I have these partials to display the items:

`views/games/_game.html.erb`

```
<%= content_tag_for :li, game do %>
  <span class="name"><%= game.name %></span>
  <% if game.players.any? %>
    <ul class="player_list">
      <%= render :partial => 'players/player', :collection => game.players %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`views/players/_player.html.erb`

```
<%= content_tag_for(:li, player) do %>
  <span class="name"><%= player.name %></span>
  <span class="delete">
    <%= link_to "delete", player, :method => :delete, :class => :delete %>
  <span>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that I want players to display differently in different contexts. For example, players should not be "delete-able" from the game show page like they might on the player index. Is it acceptable to create another partial like `views/games/_player.html.erb` that determines how players are displayed in the context of a game? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say:

> "Is it acceptable to create another partial like
>   views/games/_player.html.erb that determines how players are displayed
>   in the context of a game"

I believe that is **not the purpose** of a partial.

It seems you are giving logic to the view, and that is somehow wrong.  I believe you could have a method in a helper that would do that decision logic.

So, here is what I think I would do it in the example that you gave:

1. Have several partials that render different stuff (context dependent).
2. Create a method in a helper that will analyze the context and choose a partial to render.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I understand correctly, you saying that I should have a helper method that I call in the _player partial to decide whether or not I display the delete link given the context? In other words, the view calls for a delete button but a helper method (or a presenter) determines whether or not it is displayed?

Comment: If the logic is kind of complex yes, put it in a helper, otherwise you can do a minor conditional in the partial itself.  I thought you wanted to render different partials depending on the context though.